# Flutter - Different click actions for Web and Android in single project

Tags: flutter, youtubeplayer

I wanna implement YoutubePlayer in my Flutter project which runs in web and android platforms. I'm using youtube_player_flutter package for Android and embedded YouTube player view in web. How to separate both codes in single project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dart:io` packages `Platform` class to check the Platform that is running the code.

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html, there exists

`Platform.isAndroid`.

To check if you are deploying to web, there is a constant called `kIsWeb` in the flutter foundation. Use can use it like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // use this for web
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // use this for android
}
```